# Is titanium a native application developing platform?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, titanium

I have learnt three types of mobile applications ..
1.Web apps
2.Hybrid apps(phonegap)
3.Native apps

some say native apps are apps running on device as normal apps do( with app icon and doesnt rely on web browser as phonegap apps do)...
but some people say native apps are apps build in native language..
eg.ios apps by objective-c & swift and java(android sdk) for developing android apps.

I know titanium is cross platform apps developing sdk...

My question is apps developed by titanium are native apps or just cross platform apps ?????
Please some one help...
Thanks in advance....

Comment: you already gave the answer yourself: depends on how you define 'native'. I personally would say, yes, it's native. But that's just an opinion

Answer (score 0):

Apps developed in titanium have native like UI and functionality but the apps developed in titanium can not be called as native.Also titanium do not provide all the functionalities as apps developed in native platforms do. Titanium uses different modules. When developing apps for hybrid platforms, titanium is a better option for that.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your own question. Since Titanium offers a cross platform framework for different platforms it cannot be called native. Natively developed apps are always programmed in the respective system's programming language. You can have a look at [techopedia.com](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/27568/native-mobile-app), they offer a full definiton:

> A native mobile app is a smartphone application that is coded in a
>   specific programming language, such as Objective C for iOS and Java
>   for Android operating systems. Native mobile apps provide fast
>   performance and a high degree of reliability. They also have access to
>   a phone's various devices, such as its camera and address book. In
>   addition, users can use some apps without an Internet connection.
>   However, this type of app is expensive to develop because it is tied
>   to one type of operating system, forcing the company that creates the
>   app to make duplicate versions that work on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The parts of a Titanium apps that is definitely native are the UI elements.  JavaScript is used behind the scenes to control the logic of the app.  So, the JavaScript ties together the native UI elements.  Is it 100% converting the code to Java or Objective-C?  No.  Does it matter?  That depends on the requirements of your particular app.  Always good to experiment with any platform before deciding if it is right for you.